# invalid operands to binary expression when overloading a operator

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to write a c++ program which implements a simple Matrix with mul and add operator overloading. My matrix is stored in a simple Vector. I also overloaded the () operator to easily store the values in my Matrix.

```
template < typename T1, int rows, int cols>  
class Matrix{
public:
int row = rows;
int line = cols;
vector<T1> local_matrix;
Matrix(){
    local_matrix = vector<T1>(rows*cols, 0);
}
T1 &operator () (int i, int j){
    return local_matrix.at(i * cols +j);
}
const Matrix<T1, rows, cols> operator* (const Matrix<T1, rows, cols> &other)     const{
    Matrix<T1, other.row, other.line> result; // store the result here
    int sum_elements_i = 0;
    int left_counter = 0; // counter to iterate over the left Matrix
    int right_counter = 0; // and for the right one
    for(int i = 0; i < rows -1;++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < other.spalte -1; ++j){
            sum_elements_i = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < other.reihe -1; ++k){
                sum_elements_i += local_matrix.at(left_counter) * other.local_matrix.at(right_counter);
                left_counter++; // get the next value of the left matrix
                right_counter += other.line; // and the next one of the right here we need to skip n-elements
                                            // so its the 1st/2nd/.. value of the next line
            }
            right_counter = j+1;
            result(i, j) = sum_elements_i;
        }
        left_counter = i+1;
    }
    return result;
}
};
```

My Problem with the * operator is that everytime i want to multiply a 4x3 with a 3x3 matrix the program crashes with the following errormsg:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('Matrix<int, 4, 3>' and 'Matrix<int, 3, 3>')
E = D*A;
    ~^~
```

And here is the Code I'm calling my function:

```
Matrix<int, 3, 3> A; // Datatype, Rows, Columns 
A(0,0) = 1; A(0,1) = 2; A(0,2) = 3;
A(1,0) = 1; A(1,1) = 2; A(1,2) = 3;
A(2,0) = 1; A(2,1) = 2; A(2,2) = 3;

Matrix<int, 4, 3> D, E;
D(0,0) = 1; D(0,1) = 2; D(0,2) = 3;
D(1,0) = 4; D(1,1) = 5; D(1,2) = 6;
D(2,0) = 7; D(2,1) = 8; D(2,2) = 9;
D(3,0) = 7; D(3,1) = 8; D(3,2) = 9;

std::cout << std::endl << "D:\n" << D << std::endl;

E = D*A;
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: By "program crashes" I assume that you mean the compiler? Oh, and could you provide the class definition for the matrix (just the header file for now). I have a few thoughts but want to confirm them.

Comment: Can you add a simple definition of `Matrix` to the question?  I have my assumption but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: Oh yes, of cause only the compiler is giving me this errormsg. The program is not "crashing" at all. By the way I'm using C++11 on QT 5_5_1.  - Hey Matt yes. here is my definition: 
template < typename T1,  int rows, int cols>
class Matrix{
public:
    int row = rows;
    int line = cols;
    vector<T1> local_matrix;
    Matrix(){
        local_matrix = vector<T1>(rows*cols, 0);
    }

    T1 &operator () (int i, int j){
            return local_matrix.at(i * cols +j);
    }
};

Comment: Most likely, you do not have a * opearator for differen sizes of matrix

Comment: Not your main issue, but the constructor would be more effectively written as `Matrix(): local_matrix(rows*cols, 0) {}`

Comment: what is `other.spalte` and `other.reihe` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have defined your function, your function has the signature `Matrix<int, 4, 3> Matrix<int, 4, 3>::operator(const Matrix<int, 4, 3> &) const` which means that you would have to try to multiply a 4 by 3 matrix with a 4 by 3 matrix and that it would somehow give you another 4 by 3 matrix.  What you want instead, at minimum, is to declare your `operator*` as

```
    template <int cols2>
    Matrix<int, rows, cols2> operator*(const Matrix<int, cols, cols2> & other) const {...}
```

That will allow you multiply, for example, a 4 by 3 matrix with a 3 by 3 matrix and that will correctly output a 4 by 3 matrix.

Another change you can make to allow more types of matrices to be multiplied together is to make the signature

```
  template <class T2, int cols2>
  Matrix<typename std::common_type<T, T2>::type, rows, cols2> 
      operator*(const Matrix<T2, cols, cols2> & other) const {...}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, changing the signature of my function was the key! Now everything is working fine :) Cheers

Answer (score 3):

you have to use correct matrix size for `operator *`:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t K, std::size_t M>
Matrix<T, N, M> operator* (const Matrix<T, N, K>& lhs, const Matrix<T, K, M>& rhs);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but this isn't working fine for me. No I'm getting the following compiler error: "redefinition of parameter 'other' "  But I guess your trying to overload the operator now with three values and the program is picking the right one? I've also updated my question with the definition of my header file. -Cheers

Comment: The `Matrix` has `int` as its size type so it's probably best to stick with `int` there (unless you go and change everything to `size_t`).  Also, his current logic inside `operator*` relies on `0 - N` giving signed `-1`.

Comment: @M.M: Answered before the edit which provides Matrix definition, and indeed, type size should be coherent for the whole class.

Comment: @VicKaczm: This operator is a free function and not a member function.